# preserve the actions/state of UI with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Is there any way with angular-ui-router to actually preserve the state of the UI like most native apps do?
For example, if I was on the home view and I clicked an accordion list which expanded, then clicked on that item inside the list and navigated to another view. Next, I decide to go back to the home view. The result I would like to have is the accordion list still expanded when navigating back to the home view rather than refreshing the page.

Is there any way to preserve the actions/state of UI we navigating back and forth between views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout ui-router [extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home). I think "Deep State Redirect" probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I would say both Sticky States + Deep State Redirect

Comment: This solution seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm having trouble getting it to work though. I've included ct-ui-router-extras.js in my index.html, added 'ct.ui.router.extras' to my module, and applied to the state section sticky: true & deepStateRedirect: true to my home view, where I have an accordion present. When I attempt to return to the page, the home view still refreshes the screen/view and the controller is being recalled. Am I missing something?(Maybe if I can get the controller from call itself again, that may help. I'm not sure)

Comment: I think I'm missing something with ui-view. Let me check that out

Comment: I currently have a single page app with no tabs. How would this work for a simple app that has 4 views and I only want to preserve 1 view's state UI? (I was confused how I could apply the tabs example on ui-router-extras to my single page app & navigation structure)

Comment: Did you use a named ui-view for the sticky state?

Comment: @ChrisT Thanks, this has been killing me.  Is the requirement for the ui-view to be named called out in the documentation?  It definitely wasn't obvious to me.